# inconsistent font size when using media queries and browser zoom

Tags: html, css, media-queries, font-size, zooming

I've created the following html page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"  />
    <style>
        @media only screen and (max-width: 320px)
        {
            .text
            {                
                font-size:0.3em;
            }
        }
        @media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 480px)
        {
            .text
            {                
                font-size:0.6em;
            }
        }
        @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 600px)
        {
            .text
            {                
                font-size:0.9em;
            }
        }
        @media only screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 768px)
        {
            .text
            {                
                font-size:1.2em;
            }
        }
        @media only screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px)
        {
            .text
            {                
                font-size:1.5em;
            }
        }
        @media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1200px)
        {
            .text
            {                
                font-size:1.8em;
            }
        }
        @media only screen and (min-width: 1201px)
        {
            .text
            {                
                font-size:2em;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="text">            
            text text text text
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

when I zoom in from 100% to 500% using the broswer default steps (100%, 110%, 125%, ...) the font size increases in the few first steps and then decreases in some of the following steps in an inconsistent manner. this happens in all major browsers:
- chrome 51.0.2704.103
- ie 11
- firefox 43.0.1
any help will be appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zoom makes the font bigger. Your media query makes the font smaller. These two fight each other.

This happens because when zoom makes pixels larger, fewer pixels fit in the window, and this makes media queries for smaller windows match.

This behavior is specific to desktop browsers. Mobile browsers don't use window size for media queries, but screen size instead ([roughly](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html)).

---

In other cases where font sizes are weird, it could be because of [`text-size-adjust`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust).

Comment: thanks for the answer, the purpose of the media queries is to create break points and make the page responsive to window resizing on desktop, but the problem is (as mentioned) the browser zooming functionality isn't working well with the media queries, is there a way to achieve them both without using javascript ?

Comment: Zooming functionality works *exactly as intended* with media queries. Don't forget that CSS `px` unit **is not a screen pixel**, but an abstract point of a variable size, which is made larger or smaller by zooming.

Comment: I understand that it works fine by definition but in some cases when the user zooming in the font size decreases contradicting the user expected result, is there a way to prevent that and achieve the user expected result when zooming in ?

Comment: No, I don't think so, because the browser does what you (unintentionally) told it to. Your code says "when fewer pixels are in the window, make the font smaller", and zooming in makes fewer pixels fit in the window. You would have to stop making font smaller on smaller viewports (delete `font-size` from your media queries).